# How to mirror a replicated database

Tags: sql-server-2012, transactional-replication, mirroring

Forgive me if this question has already been asked - I've hunted around, but can't find something that matches my situation.

Say I have my Principle server (DB1), with a database Mir1.  I set up mirroring with my Mirror server (DB2).  Everything is fine.  I can failover, and see the Principle move from DB1 to DB2, and I can see it go back again.

Now, imagine we need a new database called Mir1DW, which is a replicated database off Mir1.  The distributor is on another machine altogether (DB3).

I need this Mir1DW database to be available, and to be continually updated (via replication) after the mirroring has done a failover.

I'm struggling to work out what's required.  I can find plenty of examples of mirroring with replication where the agents (using PublisherFailoverPartner) change where the data is coming from, but (from what I gather), the Mir1DW database itself is not included in the mirroring.

I've got a few limitations that I need to work within -

- Must be in SQL 2012 Standard (Enterprise not an option)
- Both the Mir1 and Mir1DW databases must be available and functioning correctly after a failover
- The Mir1 and Mir1DW databases must be on the same server (i.e., both on DB1 when running normally)

Now, I assume I would need a publisher on DB1 and DB2 (and probably DB3), and a subscription on either/both DB1 and DB2.  But I can't get my head around how to get subscriptions to play ball with mirroring.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why worry about mirroring that database? Move non-replicated tables to another DB for cross database joins (if there are other tables in there) and just replicate to both servers.

Comment: @Nic it's difficult to get into briefly, but we can't change the structure of the databases for this

Comment: Mirroring is only available for the publisher/distributor databases (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151799.aspx). While you can mirror a subscriber you would need to drop and redo publications to hit the other host on failover (lots of work, but could be scripted). I'm not sure if you are in a position to go to that level of effort or not, but really your only path forward given your restrictions.